# Bundle install fails with: Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, ruby-on-rails-4

I currently can't run `bundle install`. It always fails:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching source index from https://rubygems.org/
Updating git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
fatal: Could not parse object 'a9949c1524205928b18597f840e83478ba97c2ef'.
Git error: command `git reset --hard a9949c1524205928b18597f840e83478ba97c2ef` in directory /Users/noxoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@tp-usevalue/bundler/gems/active_admin-a9949c152420 has failed.
If this error persists you could try removing the cache directory '/Users/noxoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@tp-usevalue/cache/bundler/git/active_admin-d67faab65e9b74efbc8efb4a777a851e9f78b2ca'
```

I already tried to remove the cache directory as advised. This is my Gemfile (sorted, comments stripped):

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'active_link_to'
gem 'activeadmin'
gem 'coffee-rails'
gem 'compass-rails'
gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
gem 'devise',              github: 'plataformatec/devise'
gem 'formtastic',          github: 'justinfrench/formtastic'
gem 'inherited_resources', github: 'josevalim/inherited_resources'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
gem 'rails'
gem 'rails-i18n', '~> 4.0.0.pre' # For 4.0.x
gem 'ransack'
gem 'responders',          github: 'plataformatec/responders'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

group :development, :test do
  gem "rb-fsevent", "~> 0.9.1"
  gem "guard", "1.6.2"
  gem "guard-spork"
  gem "guard-rspec", "2.5.1"
  gem "rspec-rails", "2.13.1"
  gem "shoulda-matchers", "2.1.0"
  gem "capybara", "2.1.0"
  gem "launchy", "2.2.0"
  gem 'spork-rails', :github => 'sporkrb/spork-rails'
  gem "thin"
end
```

What really confuses me, is that it worked just fine a couple of days ago.

**UPDATE**:

As zrl3dx suggested, I removed the `Gemfile.lock` and ran `bundle` again - which results in this error:

```
$ bundle
Updating git://github.com/gregbell/active_admin.git
Updating git://github.com/milgner/compass-rails.git
Updating git://github.com/plataformatec/devise.git
Updating git://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic.git
Updating git://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources.git
Updating git://github.com/ernie/ransack.git
Updating git://github.com/plataformatec/responders.git
Updating git://github.com/sporkrb/spork-rails.git
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "ransack":
  In Gemfile:
    activeadmin (>= 0) ruby depends on
      ransack (>= 1.0.0) ruby

    ransack (0.7.3)

Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "railties":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      railties (= 4.0.0) ruby

    coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0) ruby depends on
      railties (4.0.0.rc2)
```

Comment: weird error indeed, have you tried removing the entire rubygems cache for that particular gemset and just redownloading it?

Comment: Strange, as `coffee-rails` has `railties 4.0.0` in dependencies. Maybe try running `bundle update`?

Comment: @zrl3dx `bundle update` yields the same error.

Comment: @treehau5 it's a new and empty gemset (rvm). Tried with another new and empty gemset - still same error.

Comment: Have you tried my updated answer?

Comment: @zrl3dx Ha, I just solved it myself minutes ago and made the exact same changes! Thanks for everything! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try removing `Gemfile.lock` and doing `bundle` again.

Try adding to Gemfile:

```
gem 'coffee-rails', git: 'git://github.com/rails/coffee-rails.git'
```

instead of:

```
gem 'coffe-rails'
```

Edit:

Ok, I have copied it locally and tried to resolve, my changes:

```
gem 'coffee-rails', git: 'git://github.com/rails/coffee-rails.git'
gem 'activeadmin',         github: 'gregbell/active_admin', branch: 'rails4'
gem 'rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/rails.git', branch: '4-0-stable'
gem 'devise'
gem 'ransack'
gem 'sass-rails', git: 'https://github.com/rails/sass-rails.git'
```

and now it checks out, at least here.

Comment: I removed it and got a new error. I updated my question accordingly.

Comment: It still fails on devise and/or ransack :/

Answer (score 2):

The rails4 branch of Active Admin referenced in the accepted answer no longer exists.  It has been merged into master but has not yet been released on rubygems.  This gemfile entry will reference the newest commit with rails4 support.

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'gregbell/active_admin', :ref=> 'fe7d6a6e1bafc9e9dd765dfb3a09245ccd0b3cfd'
```

Answer (score 0):

If found this worked for me:

`unset GIT_DIR`

Found from https://github.com/mislav/git-deploy/issues/27

Comment: For others wondering whether this will also help them, GIT_DIR is only relevant if your problem occurs with the git-deploy project. If you're just running bundler locally, this is a red herring.